# Do vectors necessarily have full rank?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

My understanding is that an $m$ by $n$ matrix has full rank if and only if

1. It has $\min\{m, n\}$ linearly independent columns, and
2. It has $\min\{m, n\}$ linearly independent rows

Now, a vector is a matrix with either one row or one column. That is, it is a matrix such that $\min\{m, n\} = 1$. It would thus seem that a vector has full rank if and only if

1. It has 1 linearly independent column, and
2. It has 1 linearly independent row

But that seems to hold trivially. So am I right in thinking that all vectors have full rank? And in particular, does the zero vector have full rank?

Comment: In this sense, the $0$ vector has rank $0$.  We don't normally think of a vector as a linear transformation, so the concept of rank is not really applicable, in my view.  If we think of a matrix as representing a linear transformation, with respect to some pair of bases, then the rank is the dimension of the range of the transformation.  It's true that we can relate this to a property of the matrix itself, considered just as a rectangular array of numbers, but I don't find it very meaningful when divorced from the underlying algebra.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A single vector is a linearly independent set/family if and only if it is non-zero, as you can see from the definition of linear independence.

Comment: Many thanks for such a quick answer! However, could you briefly explain *why* the zero vector does not have full rank? (In the question, I provided a reason to think that it does have full rank.)

Comment: @afreelunch The zero vector is in the span of any set. Indeed, $\operatorname{span}(\emptyset) = \{0\}$. Thus the set $\{0\}$ can be "trimmed" to $\emptyset$, retaining the same span.

Comment: @afreelunch What does the definition of linearly independent family say?

Comment: @LukeCollins That does not quite capture the point, in my opinion.

Comment: @Gae.S. Say we have a $n$ by $1$ column vector. My thinking was that this vector has 1 linearly independent column since this column cannot be written as a linear combination of any other column (since they aren't any other columns!) I guess I am missing something though?

Comment: @afreelunch Ah, ok you like that definition. Then, user LukeCollins' argument that $0$ is in the span of the empty family is what you're looking for.

Comment: Personally, I prefer the definition that an indexed family of vectors $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ is linearly independent if and only if the only indexed family of coefficients $\{a_i\}_{i\in I}$ such that (1) $a_i=0$ for all but finitely many values of $i$ and (2) $\sum_{i\in I}a_iv_i=0$ is the identically zero sequence. By that definition, $1\cdot\mathbf 0=\mathbf 0$, but $1\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

The rank of a matrix is the dimension of the vector space spanned by its columns (see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)).

Since a vector is a 1-column matrix, it will therefore have "full rank" in the matrix sense if the space it spans is of dimension 1 (same as the number of columns)

If the vector is non-zero, this is obviously true. If the vector is zero (all its elements are 0), then the space it spans is reduced to itself only (multiplying the zero vector with any number always gives back the zero vector). So in this case only, it will not have full rank in the matrix sense.

The vector